# How to set display name of a workflow in SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm having an issue setting the display name for a workflow on feature activation.

What I have got is a workflow that I create with a desired internal name (using SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListContentTypeAssociation to get an SPWorkflowAssociation object). Once the name is set with that method call, I set the SPWorkflowAssociation.Name to the desired display name after that, add the workflow association to the list, and then call update on the associated list.

The result I see is that the internal name and the display name are both changed (internal name is required to link between the SharePoint list and the Client Side Object Model and we need this internal name as the display name is different for other languages).

Does anyone know how to set this properly in code? It looks like something that should be possible but I'm getting no joy from my investigations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using the description field to store a 'static' name and then later find associations via this description field rather than the internal name.